# How to fetch URL variable array using $_REQUEST['variable name']

Tags: php, url

I am using a URL to fetch data stored/shown within URL. I get all the value of variable using $_REQUEST['v_name'] but if there is a array in URL how can i retrieve that value.

For Example:

```
WWW.example.com/rooms?&hid=213421&type=E
```

I got the value hid and type using

```
$hid=$_REQUEST['hid'];
```

but in URL like:

```
 WWW.example.com/rooms?&rooms=2&rooms[0].adults=2&rooms[0].children=0&rooms[1].adults=2&rooms[1].children=0
```

how can i retrieve value of adults and children in each room.

please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and see how you can access it. Also, you should use the `$_GET` array for query string variables (variables in the URL, after the `?` character).

Comment: `foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { }`

Comment: $_GET not helped me  because values stored in variable(after ? character) is retrieve by using GET or REQUEST but the array type variable not fetched

Comment: @user2092317: Can you please explain it in broad using my code.

Comment: show us what are you trying to request ?

Comment: Right now I am using the code `$_REQUEST['rooms(0).adults']` but that's not working.
 and using the answer below only return a warning and 'ARRAY'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try something like this, since most of your original `$_REQUEST` isn't really an array (because of the `.`s in between each key/value pair):

```
<?php
$original_string = rawurldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
$original_string_split = preg_split('/&/', $original_string);
$rooms = array();
foreach ($original_string_split as $split_one) {
  $splits_two[] = preg_split('/\./', $split_one);
}
foreach ($splits_two as $split_two) {
  if (isset($split_two[0]) && isset($split_two[1])) {
    $split_three = preg_split('/=/', $split_two[1]);
    if (isset($split_three[0]) && isset($split_three[1])) {
      $rooms[$split_two[0]][$split_three[0]] = $split_three[1];
    }
  }
}
// Print the output if you want:
print '<pre>' . print_r($rooms, 1)  . '</pre>';
```

Comment: it is working show all values but with a warning that is "UNDEFINED OFFSET ON LINE(Where the $split_three is initialize)"

Comment: Please see latest revision... Although that's a pretty common warning so if you're seeing it, you might consider changing your `display_errors` directive in your php.ini file to `'Off'` or `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
$valuse = $_GET;

foreach ($valuse as $key=>$value)
{
     echo $key .'='. $value. '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: that returns an array something like this `Array ( [rooms] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) )`

Comment: There is an error shows. " Notice: Array to string conversion on line (where i put the code)" after that return(Array)that s it